# PHP Pagination from Huge JSON array_chunk in to multiple files and getting offset

Tags: php, arrays, json, math, pagination

So I have this huge file that has 45K+ arrays and I can't just open a huge file on live server with high traffic from every request so I used `array_chunk($array, 1000)` and saved them in 46 files.

Now I want to read those files when specific page is accessed.

Problem?

`$offset` seems to be working fine with some pages but mostly offset changes to `- number` (minus number). Checked page `25, 50, 75` and more...

My Math is kinda (Very) weak, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php
    $page = ! empty( $_GET['page'] ) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $limt = 40;  //Page array/item limit
    $fcnt = 46; //Total number of files
    $tarr = 45187; //Total number of arrays
    $fmu0 = (int)($limt*$fcnt*$page/$tarr); //Getting the file number according to page number
    if(file_exists("$fmu0.json")){
    $id = json_decode(file_get_contents("$fmu0.json"),true); 

    //Each file has 1000 arrays except the last file which has 187 arrays

    $tpgs = ceil($tarr/$limt); //Total number of pages
    $mult = $fmu0*count($id);
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $limt-$mult;
    if( $offset < 0 ){$offset = 0;}
    $id = array_slice( $id, $offset, $limt );
    var_dump($id);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Also let me know if i should use `array_chunk` in this code, because i used it in making dividing huge array in to files from this function.

Comment: Calculating this `$fmu0 = (int)($limt*$fcnt*$page/$tarr);` indicates there are 24 pages per file. Is that how many pages per file? Also how many pages are in each array? Seeing example arrays helps too.

Comment: Yes, 24 Pages per file. Each file has 1000 arrays and 40 arrays when sliced so 1000/40=24 pages. Array example :https://pastebin.com/rqh16SMW

Comment: So the resulting JSON looks something like this: `[{"r": "6", "g": [2,7,8], "q": 1}, {"r": "6", "g": NULL, "q": 3}, ...]`. Each file has 1 array of 40 objects. Each object has the keys: "r", "g", and "q". There are 24 pages per file. How many objects per page? Does the number of objects per page vary from one page to another? Do any pages have objects in more than one file?

Comment: 40 objects per page but only last file might have lesser arrays because total number of arrays can vary. Each file has 1000 arrays and then divided by 40... Each object has the keys: "r", "g", and "q"... Yes and an additional key "u" is also there.

Comment: You wrote: "40 objects per page..." — How can there be 24 pages per file, and 40 objects per file, AND "40 objects per page" ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249140/discussion-between-bloodyknuckles-and-c0de-b0unty).

Comment: I have 46 files... Each file has 1000 arrays and i'm using `array_slice( $id, $offset, $limt)` so i get exact 40 arrays and it will also mean max sliced arrays will be 25... maybe i'm wrong but this is what i'm getting when i debug... My knowledge is limited in this and i'm trying something new...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000 objects per file and 40 objects per page makes 25 pages per file.

Here's how to find the file containing objects for `$page` number:

```
$fmu0 = floor($page / 25);
```

And here's how to find the starting index of the group of 40 (`$limt`) objects within that file corresponding to `$page` number, when the first page is 1:

```
$offset = (($page - 1) * $limt) - ($fmu0 * 1000);
```

---

```
<?php

$page = (!empty($_GET['page']) && 0 < $_GET['page'])
    ? (int)$_GET['page']: 1;

$limt = 40;  //Page array/item limit

// FIND FILE, 25 pages per file
$fmu0 = floor($page / 25);

if(file_exists("$fmu0.json")){
    $id = json_decode(file_get_contents("$fmu0.json"),true);     

    // FIND GROUP of 40 ($limt) page objects, 1000 objects per file
    $offset = (($page - 1) * $limt) - ($fmu0 * 1000);

    $id = array_slice( $id, $offset, $limt );
    var_dump($id);

}
?>
```

Comment: Added this in chat also... Last array still seems missing... `$offset = (($page - 1) * $limt) - ($fmu0 * $cn);`. if i change `$page - 1` to `$page` then first array becomes missing